# How to set 'selected' to a drop down with matched value with ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want the select option to be 'selected' with the value returned from ajax response.

**array**

```
$array=array("Price 1","Price 2","Price 3","Price 4","Price 5");
```

All I can thinking of is to loop until the option is matched with the given value.

```
echo "<select id='option'>";

foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  if(data.option==$key){$selected="selected";}//compare with json from ajax 
  echo "<option value='$key' $selected>$val</option>"
}

echo "</select>";
```

And I have a json response from ajax `data.option`= 1. So, is there anyway to achieve this or alternative method to do so?

Comment: Jqery inside php? there is a big difference between server-side-scripting and client-side-scritping. what's this `data.option`?

Comment: this code makes no sense. If you're dealing with an ajax response, why are you writing PHP in it? You either do it server-side and return the completed HTML as the ajax response, or you do it client-side - return your array as JSON in the ajax response, and then use JavaScript to build the HTML based on that data.

Comment: As I said. `All I can thinking of..` Because I don't know how to make it compare. So, at least please point me the way or tell me how.

Comment: so on the page select-box is created already with php code. and you want to make option as selected based on ajax response coming from another source?Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So how can I make it compare? Should I append the select with response?

Comment: @Wilf  check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want (do inside `ajax success`):-

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#option").val(data.option);//this is what you want
}
```

A demo example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#option").val(2); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='option'>
  <option value="0" selected>Price 1</option>
  <option value="1">Price 2</option>
  <option value="2">Price 3</option>
  <option value="3">Price 4</option>
  <option value="4">Price 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Um.. as I understand. `$("#option").val(2); ` will set the value to `2`? And the label `Price 3` should be selected. But it is not :(

Comment: what error you got at your end?check browser console? Also can you show us your rendered html and jQuery code

Comment: Okay, I've got the idea. If the compare is something else but a number - it'not working. I compared the value with response. So it's not working. Thanks to you!!!

Comment: @Wilf  glad to help you :)_:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#option").val(2); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='option'>
  <option value="0" selected>Price 1</option>
  <option value="1">Price 2</option>
  <option value="2">Price 3</option>
  <option value="3">Price 4</option>
  <option value="4">Price 5</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#option").val(2); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='option'>
  <option value="0" selected>Price 1</option>
  <option value="1">Price 2</option>
  <option value="2">Price 3</option>
  <option value="3">Price 4</option>
  <option value="4">Price 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.